# Google sheet + App Script : Rename every sheet if it meet criteria

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm using this script to rename every sheet by inserting 'Copy of' in front of the existing sheet name where the text in cell 'B36' = 'SAFETY ANALISIS' and the date from cell 'K3'is older then 30 days. My issue is having to do with the date I can't quite figure how to do it. Cell 'K3' cell are in this format "1-Aug-2021" I think I need to convert the date in 'K3' to a number format.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
function getSheet() {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];
        var date = new Date();
        var ageInDays = 30;
        var threshold = new Date(
                      date.getFullYear(),
                      date.getMonth(),
                      date.getDate() - ageInDays)
                    .getTime();

        var val = sheet.getRange('K3').getValue();
        var val2 = sheet.getRange('B36').getValue();
       
       


        if (val >= threshold && val2 == 'SAFETY ANALYSIS') {
            var sheetName = sheet.getName()
            sheet.setName('Copy Of '+sheetName)  
        }       
    }

  
}
```

Comment: Is the cell containing the date formatted as a date, or is it formatted as text or normal?

Comment: when I run debugger it come up in this format
the value for val ('K3')
Sun Aug 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)

Comment: It already returns a ``date``. `var val = sheet.getRange('K3').getValue().getTime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getSheet() {
  const shts = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  let d = new Date();
  let ageInDays = 30;
  let threshold = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate() - ageInDays).valueOf();
  shts.forEach(sh => {
    let val = new Date(sh.getRange('K3').getValue()).valueOf();
    let val2 = sh.getRange('B36').getValue();
    if (val <= threshold && val2 == 'SAFETY ANALYSIS') {
      sh.setName('Copy Of ' + sh.getName())
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help Ive just tried the answer from Cooper and it's working good the only thing I had to change was the val >= threshold to val <= threshold and now it's renaming all sheets with a date older then 30 days thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You may want to wrap the value you get from cell `K3` in a `Date()` constructor. That should work with spreadsheet dates as well as text strings that look like dates.

I think you have the comparison in `val >= threshold` the wrong way around. Try something like this:

```
function renameOldSafetyAnalysisSheets() {
  const timeLimit = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 30 days
  const now = new Date();
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (sheet.getRange('K3').getValue() !== 'SAFETY ANALYSIS') {
      return;
    }
    const date = new Date(sheet.getRange('B36').getValue());
    if (!date.getTime()
      || now.getTime() - date.getTime() < timeLimit) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      sheet.setName('Copy of ' + sheet.getName());
    } catch (error) {
      ;
    }
  });
}
```